# necesito que la clave salga así **** o algo similar (Cree solución parcial, pero busco algo mejor para cifrado de información)

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5, razor

> Solución parcial:

```
      [Display(Name = "Password")]
      [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "••••••••••")]
      [Required(ErrorMessage = "Requiere {0}")]
      [DataType(DataType.Password)]
      public string pass_usuario { get; set; }
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

> EN el listado de usuarios que tiene el administrador de sistema la clave debe mostrarse de esta forma "****" o cifrada como el común de las contraseñas (sólo puntos). Intento hacer replace, porque no me permite usar passwordfor.
>   EL listado de usuario se muestra así, más o menos:
>   [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
>    Pero no quiero que la contreseña sea visible. Puse la clase del modelo, ahí se daran cuenta que el dataanotations no sirve para este caso.

model-usuario

```
      public class Usuario
{
    [Key]
    public int id_usuario { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Login")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Requiere {0}")]
    public string name_usuario { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Password")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Requiere {0}")]
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    public string pass_usuario { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Perfil")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Requiere {0}")]
    public int id_perfil { get; set; }

    public virtual Perfil Perfil { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Administrador_sistema> Administradores_sistema { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Analista_abastecimiento> Analistas_abastecimiento { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Gerente_abastecimiento> Gerentes_abastecimiento { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Jefe_abastecimiento> Jefes_abastecimiento { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Vendedor> Vendedores { get; set; }
}
```

}

---

```
     @model IEnumerable<Supermercado.Models.Usuario>

     @{
ViewBag.Title = "Index";
Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}
<h2>Index</h2>

<p>
@Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create")
</p>
<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Perfil.name_perfil)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.name_usuario)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.pass_usuario)
        </th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>

@foreach (var item in Model) {
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Perfil.name_perfil)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.name_usuario)
        </td>
        <td>
            /*Aquí está mi códigoooooo*/
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.pass_usuario.ToString().Replace(@"[^A-Za-z0-9/\s/g]", "*"))
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id=item.id_usuario }) |
        @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id=item.id_usuario }) |
        @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id=item.id_usuario })
    </td>
</tr>
}
</table>
```

Comment: Creo que la forma correcta para que Razor enmascare la entrada del usuario en un input de tipo password es que utilices los DataAnnotations apropiados para este tipo de campo en tu modelo. Por ejemplo: [DataType(DataType.Password)] http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/a8024d/validation-using-data-annotations-in-Asp-Net-mvc-5/

Answer (score 9, accepted):

En tu `model`, define la propiedad `pass_usuario` como tipo *password*:

```
[Required]
[StringLength(100, ErrorMessage = "El campo Contraseña es requerido")]
[DataType(DataType.Password)]
[Display(Name = "Contraseña")]
public string pass_usuario{ get; set; }
```

En mismo IDE lo tomará en automático como una contraseña mostrará el campo enmascarado.

En el `View`, simplemente manda llamar a la propiedad sin la expresión regular:

```
<td>
    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.pass_usuario)
</td>
```

Comment: Voté por reabrir la pregunta , en efecto es bastante clara y su respuesta precisa.